# Export comma separated numeric value to excel using devexpress reporting in c#

Tags: c#, devexpress, export-to-excel, xtrareport

I am exporting following values to excel in devexpress reporting(c#) and
I want to display thousand separated values without warning in excel sheet.

7.112342 is formatted and displayed as 7.11

201404   is formatted and displayed as 2014-Aprl

5166 is formatted as 5,166 but unable to display in excel.

Following is the code to export,

```
this.ExportToXls(rptPath, new XlsExportOptions(TextExportMode.Value, true));
```

When `TextExportMode.Value` is changed to `TextExportMode.Text` then comma is displaying in excel with a warning.

Image attached for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dont change **TextExportMode.Value** to  **TextExportMode.Text** to get comma seaparated numeric values in excel, rather try to export to **xlsx** file .

With the the above approach , it is supporting native format but, all users may not have support for **xlsx** files.